# Forecasting Solar Power Using VMD Decomposition and 1D CNN - Inconsistent Results Between Training and Testing

Tags: keras, time-series, conv-neural-network, forecasting, loss-function

I am working on a solar power forecasting project using Variational Mode Decomposition (VMD) decomposition followed by a 1D Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) for prediction. My data consists of a one-dimensional time series vector representing solar power.

**Problem Description:**

I performed VMD decomposition on the training data, resulting in five Intrinsic Mode Functions (IMFs).
I applied a sliding window technique to split these IMFs into smaller windows of 20 time steps each.
I trained a 1D CNN on this preprocessed data, and during testing on the training data, I achieved a reasonable test accuracy with a Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) of 85 and Mean Absolute Error (MAE) of 50. The model had not seen the test data during training.
**Issue**:
However, when I tried to apply the model to real-world data, which had not undergone the same VMD decomposition as the training data, I encountered a much higher RMSE of 256. This suggests a significant discrepancy between the performance on training data and real-world data.

**This the code:**

```
xe = loadmat('/kaggle/input/ana-howa/data3.mat')["resultats"]
print(xe.shape)ahead=0
def signal_segmentation(dt,steps,ahead):
    end=0
    start=0
    x=[]
    y=[]
    for i in range(steps,dt.shape[0]):
        if i+ahead<dt.shape[0]:
            x.append(dt[i-steps:i,0:-1])
            y.append(dt[i+ahead,-1])
    return np.array(x),np.array(y)

from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanAbsoluteError
from keras.regularizers import L1L2
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, BatchNormalization
from keras import regularizers

n_hours=24
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
print("steps:",n_hours)
x,y=signal_segmentation(xe,n_hours,ahead)
y=np.reshape(y,(-1,1))
x_trainlstm, x_testlstm, y_trainlstm, y_testlstm = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1,shuffle=True)

#x_testlstm,y_testlstm=signal_segmentation(testing,n_hours,ahead)
#x_train, x_test = b[:train_size,:], b[train_size:,:]
#y_train, y_test = n[:train_size], n[train_size:]

x_trainlstm=np.reshape(x_trainlstm,(x_trainlstm.shape[0],x_trainlstm.shape[1]*x_trainlstm.shape[2]))
x_testlstm=np.reshape(x_testlstm,(x_testlstm.shape[0],x_testlstm.shape[1]*x_testlstm.shape[2]))
scaler = MinMaxScaler((0,1)).fit(x_trainlstm)
#joblib.dump(scaler, 'scaler_model.pkl')
x_trainlstm=scaler.transform(x_trainlstm)
x_testlstm=scaler.transform(x_testlstm)
x_trainlstm=np.array(x_trainlstm, dtype=np.float64)
y_trainlstm=np.array(y_trainlstm, dtype=np.float64)
x_testlstm=np.array(x_testlstm, dtype=np.float64)
y_testlstm=np.array(y_testlstm, dtype=np.float64)
print(x_trainlstm.shape)
x_trainlstm=np.reshape(x_trainlstm,(x_trainlstm.shape[0],n_hours,features))
x_testlstm=np.reshape(x_testlstm,(x_testlstm.shape[0],n_hours,features))
print(x_trainlstm.shape)
y_trainlstm=np.array(y_trainlstm).reshape((len(y_trainlstm),1))
y_testlstm=np.array(y_testlstm).reshape((len(y_testlstm),1))
print(y_testlstm.shape)
print(y_trainlstm.shape)
print(x_trainlstm.shape)

spectrograms_test = x_testlstm[:,:,0:5]
spectrograms_train = x_trainlstm[:,:,0:5]
weather_train = x_trainlstm[:,:,5:]
weather_test = x_testlstm[:,:,5:]
spectrograms_test=np.reshape(spectrograms_test,(spectrograms_test.shape[0],spectrograms_test.shape[1], spectrograms_test.shape[2]))
spectrograms_train=np.reshape(spectrograms_train,(spectrograms_train.shape[0],spectrograms_train.shape[1], spectrograms_train.shape[2]))

import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, Dense, concatenate,GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
#from tensorflow.keras.layers.advanced_activations import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam,RMSprop,SGD,Adadelta,Adagrad,Adamax,Nadam,AdamW
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau

# Create separate input layers for spectrogram and weather data
spectrogram_input = Input(shape=(spectrograms_train.shape[1], spectrograms_train.shape[2]))
weather_input = Input(shape=(weather_train.shape[1], weather_train.shape[2]))
spectrogram_conv = Conv1D(128, kernel_size=3, padding = "same",use_bias=False,strides=1)(spectrogram_input)
spectrogram_conv = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(spectrogram_conv)

spectrogram_conv = Conv1D(96, kernel_size=2,padding = "same")(spectrogram_conv)
spectrogram_conv = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(spectrogram_conv)
spectrogram_flatten = Flatten()(spectrogram_conv)
combined = Dense(200)(spectrogram_flatten)
combined = Dense(128)(combined)
output = Dense(1, activation='relu')(combined)

# Create the model
model = Model(inputs=spectrogram_input, outputs=output)

# Compile and train the model with your data
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0003), loss='mean_absolute_error')
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_modelCNN22.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', save_best_only=True)
#early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor = 0.9, patience = 10, min_lr = 1e-7, verbose = 1)
history1=model.fit(spectrograms_train, y_trainlstm, epochs=150 , validation_split=0.1,callbacks=[mc,reduce_lr],batch_size=64,shuffle=True)
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize = (8, 7))
pyplot.plot(history1.history['loss'], label='Train')
pyplot.plot(history1.history['val_loss'], label='Validation')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.grid(True)
pyplot.show() 
saved_model = load_model('best_modelCNN22.h5')
yhat = saved_model.predict(spectrograms_test)
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_testlstm, yhat))
mino=np.mean(y_testlstm)
nrmse=rmse/mino
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_testlstm, yhat)
r2=r2_score(y_testlstm, yhat)

#resultat.append((rmse,mae,r2))
print("RMSE test {}".format(rmse))
print("NRMSE test {}".format(nrmse))
print("MAE test {}".format(mae))
print("R2 test {}".format(r2))`
```

Can someone explain the potential reasons behind such a drastic increase in error when applying the model to real-world data that was not decomposed at the time of training?
Is it recommended to perform the VMD decomposition before or after splitting the signal into windows for training and testing? Which approach is more suitable for solar power forecasting?
Are there any best practices or additional preprocessing steps that could help improve the model's performance on real-world data?